# MySQL won't start if I set the log_bin

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/db_vol/datadir
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port=3306
server_id=1
log-bin=/db_vol/log/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=mydb
```

When I try to start MySQL, I get an error that says `MySQL Daemon failed to start.`. If I comment out the `log-bin` line then it loads fine. I'm trying to set up replication so I think I need `log-bin`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does the MySQL error log say?

Comment: Most likelt this is because mysql can't write to /db_vol/log/mysql-bin.log. Look in your error log, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Does the folder /db_vol/log/ exist?
2. Do the permissions /db_vol/log/ allow write access? e.g. is the user / owner matching the mysql account and the account(s) have write access?

If your mysql user account was mysql, you could run this:

`chown mysql:mysql /db_vol/log/`

and then

`chmod 770 /db_vol/log/`